# Using computer as USB communication middleman

Tags: c#, java, usb, windows-7-x64

I want to develop a USB protocol analyser using my Windows 7 x64 PC as the communication middleman.

Using embedded systems sometimes I have two devices that "talk" through USB and I need to see what are they "saying".

My idea is too connect those two devices to my pc and tell to my application that those are the 2 ports used in the communication. Next the application will listen to both ports, log the messages and redirect it to the other port.

If there's a method to do that using raw usb data, without the need to have installed drivers for those USB devices (some of them don't have Windows drivers) that would be perfect.

I have knowledge in C# and Java but other languages are acceptable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a USB Sniffing program like [SnoopyPro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/) (freeware open source) to get the data. I do not know if it has a way to forward the capture live to your program but you can save the captures and then do post processing in your own code. This will only work if one of the endpoints is your computer.

If you have two devices that never use your computer you will likely need [specialized hardware](http://www.totalphase.com/protocols/usb/) (the cheepest one is $400 and it will not do the higher speed transfer rates, you need the $1200 model to do that.)

Comment: I would prefer to have full control on the communication in order to be able to stop one device and send my own data to the other. I know how to do that using embedded systems but I don't have any dev board for that right now

Comment: It is unlikely that this will be doable without some sort of hardware sitting between the two devices, the more I think about it the less confidant that you could even write a driver in Linux to do it as the chip-set on the motherboard is what is doing the initial handshaking. Some how you will need to make your computer emulate being both a "host" to one device and a "peripheral" to the other.

Comment: How about if I solder a USB splitter, where you have 1 female and 2 male USB connectors (being the second male to connect it to the pc) and use this just to log the exchanged messages? Do you think that the OS won't ruin the communication? I'm just avoiding to buy dev boards to solve a "not so common" problem

Comment: Once again, if you did that somehow you would need to override the normal USB behavor (handshake, ect.) which I do not think is possible in software. If you are feeling creative you can make it yourself with a FPGA but you still will need hardware (your FPGA device) to intercept the communication. If you update your question with more details of what your end goal is and what the two devices are there could be other solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

For Ethernet data: Referring to the Netfilter architecture of Linux, iptables and simple Module can be used to modify data packets. This comes from the five hook points of Linux kernel developers on Netfilter, which can facilitate the developers to operate data packets at different stages reasonably. There seems to be no neifilter-like hook architecture for USB data. To intercept and modify, this means that you need to embed your own program in the kernel for the Device<-->Host interaction phase. Finding the right spot and putting your own kernel code into it to make it work is not a simple matter.